# How to write protocol in Swift that can pass itself to a delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to write a delegate protocol where the caller can pass itself to the delegate – similar to the way the `UITableViewDelegate` operates. However, I get the error *Protocol 'ControllerDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements*. Note that `Controller` expects a generic.

Here's the code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

protocol ControllerDelegate: class{
    typealias T
    func controller(controller: Controller<T>, doSomething: String)
}

class Controller<T> {
    var delegate: ControllerDelegate?

    func foo(){
        delegate?.controller(self, doSomething: "Foo")
    }
}

class mainClass: ControllerDelegate {
    init(){
        let controller = Controller<Int>()
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.foo()
    }

    func controller(controller: Controller<Int>, doSomething: String) {
        print(doSomething)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't currently combine generics and protocols in Swift - see https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/18152#18152

Comment: Basically, you can't do this because the compiler can't guarantee you won't create, for example, a `Controller<Int>`, and set its delegate to a `ControllerDelegate` where `T` is `String`.